# STALKER mod how to run without screen leaning

Tags: mods, stalker-clear-sky

I recently bought STALKER Call of Pripyat, but I can't play long enough before I get really dizzy when you run.

Is there a mod or a fix where I can run without my screen leaning (or shaking left and right) as I get really dizzy.

It's a good game (kind of like fallout 3) but this run thing is making me have second thoughts about my purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the [No Head Bob](http://stalker.filefront.com/file/No_Head_Bob;93968) mod.