# What is "bobbing" or "head bob"?

Tags: terminology

I was looking through [Minecraft's menu options](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options) and I saw a toggle for "View Bobbing" and I didn't recognize what it meant. I've also heard of the phrase "Head bob" [from this STALKER post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80368/stalker-mod-how-to-run-without-screen-leaning), which sounds related but I'm not sure.

The Minecraft article describes the setting as:

> "Chooses whether to show the bobbing when walking."

But that's very unclear. What is "bobbing" or "head bobbing" and how do they affect the games I play?

Comment: fyi, bobbing is in not only a gaming related word. It's a normal English word also used in real life. A simple dictionary search might have answered this question for you

Comment: Why don't you turn the setting off, then walk, and compare...

Comment: @IvoBeckers It wouldn't have answered the question "how do they affect the games that I play"?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Head bobbing in first person games is swaying the camera up and down as the character walks, to simulate the way a person's body moves up and down while taking steps. When especially prominent, it can cause motion sickness in players, so turning it off can reduce those effects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105269/discussion-on-answer-by-wrigglenite-what-is-bobbing-or-head-bob).

Comment: On the other hand, some people think that a first-person view *without* head bobbing feels more like a disembodied camera or a flying drone than a person walking.